# Was there any terrorism in the Soviet Union?

Tags: soviet-union, terrorism

Did terrorist attacks ever occur within the borders of the USSR?

By this, I do **not** mean:

- terrorist acts committed by the USSR against its own people
- terrorists abroad sponsored by the USSR
- acts of terror committed within Bolshevik/Soviet territory during the Russian Civil War or World War 2

Edit: for the purpose of this question, a terrorist attack is an attempt to kill people for a political reason, by somebody other than the government.

Comment: Hijackings and alleged subway bombings by Armenian nationalists, I recall reading on that somewhere

Comment: @Deer_Hunter that's the kind of thing I mean. Be interested if anyone can spin it into an answer.

Comment: For all purposes, WWII was not over until the Russkies quashed resistance in Ukraine and the Baltics. Some of that was homebred, some was funded by the CIA just like in Tibet. Ugly stuff on both sides - entire villages razed.

Comment: Yes, there was terrorism in Lithuania, the wood fighters. Although they are glorified in modern day Lithuania as heroes, they fit exactly your definition of terrorists.

Comment: Wikipedia lists a series of airplane hijackings, mostly by people trying to evade to Western Europe/USA

Comment: What is your definition of terrorism? There are several of those, but looking into your rationale, it seems that you have yet another definition of it? For example, considering the last sentence, when two alcohol-poisoned Russians have a dispute about what country to bomb first, and this ends up with a *knife party*, would this qualify?

Comment: Mostly post World War II nationalists on formerly German-occupied territory or in previously independent states, I would think.

Comment: @bytebuster I don't understand your comment. I defined terrorism in the question. Perhaps you could tell me why it is unclear. What is a knife party?

Comment: @NeMo, you define terrorism as killing for political reasons, except when government does. Hence, if two Russians drink vodka, have argument about whether to bomb Jerusalem first or Washington, and then one of them kills another with a knife — this would match your criteria, but this is obviously **not** terrorism.

Comment: I think you should apply common sense to my definition, rather than expecting me to construct a watertight definition which deals totally with every hypothetical situation you can dream up. If you have something which really happened, tell us about it and if it reveals a problem in my defintion, I'll amend it.

Comment: @Bregalad one person's terrorist is often another person's freedom fighter. The French and Dutch resistance in WW2 were terrorists according to the Germans, freedom fighters according to the allies...

Comment: There is a joke about KGB: Some Russians have been kidnapped by the terrorists in Syria. Soon KGB caught the family members of the terrorists, cut their fingers and mailed to the terrorist to release the hostage.

Comment: @Him - isn't that a historical fact?

Comment: @Deer Hunter Four Soviet diplomats were kidnapped in1985. One was killed by his captors; the other three were released a month later. According to a 1986 report by the Jerusalem Post, the release of the hostages occurred following the kidnapping and murder of a key Hezbollah leader by the KGB.

Comment: Question is not clear about if any internal resistance movement (during revolution, during WWII and short before) count. Do mensheviks count? Technically speaking the Polish can count as terrorist (under the Soviet occupation) or the 100s thousands soviet citizens who joined the Germans against Stalin during WWII.

Comment: Read it again. I explicitly excluded ww2 and the civil war.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Russian wiki has decently good [article](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B,_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8) on terrorist attacks in Russia, including ones which took place in USSR.

- 1927 The bomb in Leningrad Communist University; 1 killed, 26 wounded; done by white emigrants terroristic organization [Russian Common-Military Union](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7)
- 1934 Kirov's murder
- 1942 Stalin assasination attempt (actually killer shoot at Mikoyan's car by mistake)
- 1947 Bombing house in Lvov; 10 killed; done by Ukrainian nationalist, member of [Ukrainian Socialist-Radical Party](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%96%D1%8F_1890)
- 1967 Bombing attempt in the Red Square (no reliable info on victims)
- 1968 [Shooting in Kursk](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8_%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0); 13 killed, 11 wounded
- 1969 Brezhnev assasination attempt
- 1971 [Bombing bus](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5) in Krasnodar; 10 killed; done by psycho due to "misanthropy"
- 1973 bomb explosion near Lenin mausoleum; 3 killed (including suicide bomber), 4 wounded; terrorist was not identified
- 1977 the series of [three bombings in Moscow](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B2_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B5_(1977)) (incl. Moscow subway); 29 killed; done by armenian nationalists
- 1990 Gorbachev assasination attempt

Also numerous (more than 15) taking hostages and plane hijackings, mostly non-politically motivated, including 1973 Tu-104 plane crash due to terrorist's bomb detonation (all 81 died).

Comment: BTW on Kirov's murder. Although the results of investigation were doubtful (it's hard to believe that just a single person could perform that action inside a well-secured area), yet we _must_ classify that murder as terroristic act anyway, just like we treat 9/11/11 - bad investigation and existence of some conspiracy theory is not a reason enough to change this.

Comment: If you're referring to the notion that Stalin did it as conspiracy theory, then it's no more so than saying the Reichstag fire was started by Hitler

Comment: This looks like it could also integrate the [Forest Brothers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forest_Brothers), who were of cause 'resistance and freedom fighters', [throwing the occasional bomb](http://www.spauda.lt/voruta/kronika/chronic6.htm). But that the last Laithuanian one seized operating in 1978 is impressive…

Comment: 1977 bombing: "29 killed"--The Wikipedia page you link to says 7 killed?

Answer (score 13):

I found the article about the bombings by Armenian nationalists: [1977 Moscow bombings (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1977_Moscow_bombings).

- It was a series of three explosions in Moscow subway and at two grocery stores in downtown Moscow (7 dead, abt. 40 injured).

I also found this page: [Террористические акты в СССР: проблема с давней историей](http://www.chuchotezvous.ru/social-disasters/311.html) (Beggin' pardon for any possible mistranslations) with more details:

- 1970 (other sources cite 1955): Arkhangelsk - a lone gunman with an automatic rifle killed several local party officials
- 1970: Brazinska's father and son hijacked a plane, killed a flight attendant, wounded two of the crew, landed in Turkey, ended up in the United States
- 1975: Georgia (a USSR republic): three explosions close to official buildings, perpetrator executed.
- 1979: somewhere near Moscow: three politically motivated explosions

Assassination attempts:

- 1942: Saveliy Dmitriev: attempted assassination of Joseph Stalin (turned out he mistook another party official for JS)
- 1969: Viktor Ilyin: Brezhnev assassination attempt
- 1990: Alexandr Schmonov: Gorbatchev assassination attempt

Other translated pages also cite:

- 1970: an attempt by 16 Soviet Jews to hijack a plane from Leningrad.
- Post-WWII (into the 1950's): insurgencies in [Ukraine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_Insurgent_Army) and [the Baltics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forest_Brothers), with numerous nasty killings and reprisals
- 1950-1980s: various small-scale killings of party officials by groups of Chechens.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I can't recall specific details but while visiting a museum of Ukrainian Nationalism in the city of Lviv in the 1990s I remember seeing a huge map covering an entire wall showing acts of terrorism allegedly committed by Ukrainian nationalists all across the Soviet Union -- there were a LOT of them and of course mostly within the territory of Ukraine, but by no means all, some even in the far reaches of Siberia, and occurring over the full lifetime of the USSR, although mostly prior to the 1970s.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there was some terrorism in the USSR.

- As you know, Kirov has been assassinated.
- Many people were accused during Stalin's era in conspiring in making terrorist acts or assassinations, it is difficult to say how much of it was true.
- After the war there were some rebels in Western Ukraine, they uses terrorist tactics (such as killing the school teachers etc).
- There were some people who allegedly attempted to shoot on Soviet leaders during public speeches (including Brezhnev). This was apparently inspired by the assassination of Kennedy.
- In the 1970s a problem emerged with plane hijackers. They usually threatened to blow up the plane and demanded a landing abroad. It was usually a way to emigrate to other countries and the hijackers rarely had real bombs and weapons.

Comment: -1: This answer badly needs prooflinks and credible references. „Many people“, „some people“, and „apparently inspired“ are just bareword statements that have nothing to do with history (and History.SE).

Comment: Tell me about the Brezhnev thing. Did he actually get shot at? When?

Comment: @Ne Mo Wikipedia has it, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brezhnev_assassination_attempt but it was not a sole attempt.

Comment: @Ne Mo funny enough it was announced that the shooter was firing at the cosmonauts. He was incarcerated into a mental hospital and released in 1990. After release he was given a flat and the military wage for 20 years because it turned out that he was not formally fired from the military.

Comment: Kirov was killed by the regime, explicitly disqualified. Same with the Stalinist purges, false accusations all over the place.

Comment: @jwenting You can't just "disqualify" Kirov's case, as it is really unclear who stood behind that. On the matter of "false accusations", at least in 1920s there were quite a few well-known terrorist groups (most famous person was [Savinkov](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)).

Comment: @jwenting even if Kirov was killed by Stalin as a political competitor, Stalin was not acting in the regime's capacity because Kirov also was part of the regime.

Comment: @Anixx nonsense. That would disqualify a large number of Stalin's victims as being ordered by the regime. You're as usual just trying to come up with excuses for Stalinism.

Comment: @jwenting is there an indication that Kirov was killed by regime's secret services rather than private people? Stalin was not in control of the secret services at the time.

Comment: @jwenting if you disagree with the Kirov assassination 'counting', why don't you also talk about it in Matt's answer, as it is, you're obviously picking on Anixx here.

Comment: Sorry -1. I am balking at the second bullet. There's *nothing* difficult about evaluating the Stalin-era accusations of terrorism and espionage - they were all trumped-up fabricated charges. People were tortured into confessing to these "crimes" but no evidence save for these manifestly false confessions was ever produced. In most cases no trial was held - people were arrested, tortured, signed the confession, "tried" in absentia and en bloc with others, and then shot/sent to a gulag camp. The "trial" usually consisted of 3 people signing off on a list of name in a matter of minutes.

Comment: All this is *very* well known so I resent the attempt to obfuscate the matter.